# How I can prove the converse of this result?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that:

1) $g$ has infinitely many real zeros.

2) $g$ assumes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values, i.e., for all $K>0$, there are $s₁,s₂$ with $g(s₁)<-K$ and $g(s₂)>K$.

Then we can prove that the fiber $g⁻¹(w)$ is infinite for all $w∈ℝ$.

My **question** is: How I can prove the converse of this result?

Comment: I guess $g$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $g$ has infinitely many zeros because the fiber $g^{-1}(0)$ is infinite.

Let $K > 0$ and $w=K+1$. Since $g^{-1}(w)$ is infinite, it is nonempty, hence there is $s_2$ such that $g(s_2)=w=K+1 > K$. In the same way, $g^{-1}(-K-1)$ is nonempty, so there is $s_1$ such that $g(s_1)=-K-1 < -K$.

Comment: @AR1: the sine function is bounded so...